# ¿Cómo puedo timbrar un XML de tercero en SDK de Contpaq?

Tags: .net, sdk

Quiero usar el SDK de Contpaq para facturar un xml de tercero  y al intentar me arroja un error -1 [plataforma].

utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Compacw\\Facturacion");

        int paq = FacturaSDK.fSetNombrePAQ("CONTPAQ I Facturacion");
        Console.WriteLine("error pac" + paq);
        int status = FacturaSDK.fInicializaSDK();
        int statusEmpresa = 0;
        string Ruta = "PRIME SA DE CV";
        if (status == 0)
        {
            string lDirectorioEmpresa = "C:\\Compacw\\Empresas\\";
            statusEmpresa = FacturaSDK.fAbreEmpresa(lDirectorioEmpresa + Ruta);
            if (statusEmpresa == 0)
            {
                int lError = FacturaSDK.fInicializaLicenseInfo(1);
                if (lError == 0)
                {
                    string aRutaXML = lDirectorioEmpresa + Ruta + "\\F001.xml";
                    string aCodConcepto = "4";
                    string aRutaDDA = "";
                    string aPass = "password";
                    string aRutaFormato = "C:\\Compacw\\Empresas\\Reportes\\Facturacion\\Formato_Factura_40.htm";
                    string aRutaResultado = lDirectorioEmpresa + Ruta + "\\Doctos\\";
                    StringBuilder aUUID = new StringBuilder();
                    int Licencia = FacturaSDK.fInicializaLicenseInfo(1); //  iniciar licencia 
                    int factura = FacturaSDK.fTimbraXML(aRutaXML, aCodConcepto, aUUID, aRutaDDA, aRutaResultado, aPass, aRutaFormato);
                    Console.WriteLine("error fac" + factura);

                    if (factura != 1)
                    {
                        StringBuilder aMensaje = new StringBuilder();
                        int aLong = 400;

                        FacturaSDK.fError(factura, aMensaje, aLong);
                        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time} error de la app "+factura, DateTimeOffset.Now);
                            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            FacturaSDK.fCierraEmpresa();
        }
   

        // se cierra conexion a SDK
        FacturaSDK.fTerminaSDK();
```

La función que regresa el error es la fTimbraXML que al mandarle los parámetros solamente regresa -1

El sistema es ContPaqi Factura Electrónica.
Tengo el SDK y los DLLS que se deben de utilizar.
La documentación me dice lo siguiente:
donde MGW_SDK es un dll que es la interfaz de comunicación.